# Including value of int variable inside of string

Tags: c++, casting

I am trying to print the date that the user enters in a program I am working on. In this *very simplified* example, I am trying to get the value of an `int` variable inside of a `string` variable. Here, you can see I have tried `static_cast<char>(int)`.
I have also tried

- `myStr = num;`
- `myStr = num + 0;`
- `myStr = num + '0';`

as well as many other things that do not make sense just to see what the compiler does and what the program does - if I can get it to run.

Here's the few lines I have in this shortened example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num = 100;
    string myStr = static_cast<char>(num);
    cout << myStr;
    return 0;
}
```

In my other program, I am trying to insert the year 2017 (saved as an `int` variable) into a string that contains the rest of the date. I'm just having problems with numbers bigger than 9.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the standard library function [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to convert your number to string form.

Comment: I can't believe I couldn't find this function from all the googling I did. Just to follow up - could using this function be considered part of bad practice? Thanks so much!

Comment: @Tanner Causey Why on earth would you consider using `std::to_string` bad practice? It was added to the standard library to facilitate conversions of numbers to string form without having to muck about with stringstreams and the like. If anything, using it is *good* practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
stringstream ss;
ss << num;  
cout << ss.str();
```

Don't forget to include sstream

As of the C++11 standard, string-to-number conversion and vice-versa are built in into the standard library and you could use to_string method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **to_string** to convert int to String.

```
#include<String>
std::string int_string = std::to_string(num);
```

If you have older version of c++,this will work by compiling with the flag -stdc++=11 or higher e.g

```
g++ filename.cpp -stdc++=11
```